# Jest mock an ES module imported by an http server controller

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

I have a basic express server that I test with Jest and Supertest. I am trying to mock an ES module that is imported by a controller. Testing works fine, but I couldn't make the mocking work. Here are some snippets, you can also see the project setup and config through the link below.

[minimal reproduction repo](https://github.com/ylmzKasap/jest-ESM-mock-test)

```
// message_controller.js
import moduleToMock from './module_to_mock.js';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { message } = req.body;

  const mockWorks = moduleToMock(); // Returns false by default, must be mocked to return true
  if (!mockWorks) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Mock did not work'});
  }

  return res.status(200).json({message: `Mock works: ${message}`});
}
```

```
// message_controller.test.js
jest.unstable_mockModule('./module_to_mock.js', () => 
  jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true) 
);

test('Mock successfully', async () => {
  const messageToSend = 'hello';
  const response = await server.post('/message').send(
    {message: messageToSend}
  );

  expect(response.body.message).toEqual(`Mock works: ${messageToSend}`);
});
```

I have seen the issue [10025](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/10025) where folks are using "await import()" to make it work, but I am not even sure whether it would be applicable in this case since I am not using the imported module directly in the test file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `module_to_mock.js` module uses default export, so you need to mock the function like:

```js
jest.unstable_mockModule('./module_to_mock.js', () => {
  return {
    default: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true),
  };
});
```

2. From the [Module mocking in ESM](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm) documentation, you need to use dynamic `import()` to import the `app.js` module in your test.

The final code:

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

jest.unstable_mockModule('./module_to_mock.js', () => {
  return {
    default: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true),
  };
});

test('Mock successfully', async () => {
  const app = (await import('./app')).default;
  const server = request(app());
  const messageToSend = 'hello';
  const response = await server.post('/message').send({ message: messageToSend });

  expect(response.body.message).toEqual(`Mock works: ${messageToSend}`);
});
```

Test result:

```bash
(node:9201) ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
 PASS  ./message_controller.test.js
  ✓ Mock successfully (73 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.35 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```